# Does Apollo's passive break cap?

Tags: smite

> Audacity: After 10 successful basic attacks, Apollo gains Audacity, attacking with both hands and increasing his attack speed by 100% for the next 5 attacks (hit or miss) he makes.

The cap on attack speed is 2.5. Can Audacity break this?

Answer (score 2):

[No.](http://www.smitefire.com/smite/forum/theory-crafting/apollo-attack-speed-and-audacity-1266) Audacity does not break the attack speed cap; it is a hard cap.